# Plotly JS - Render Charts as Images

Tags: plotly, puppeteer, plotly.js

I have dashboards built with Plotly.js that are very big... in excess of 100+ charts with thousands of data points.  I'm using Puppeteer to generate PDF reports from these dashboards.

I'm currently rendering Plotly graphs as such:

```
config.staticPlot = true;
config.responsive = false;

Plotly.react("#div", data, layout, config);
```

Even if "staticPlot" is set to true, the plots get rendered as SVG.  When printing these charts to PDF, it generates SVG in the PDF as well, where the PDF becomes enormously big and the process ridiculously slow.

So my question: is there a way to render the plots as JPG or any image format which will not be printed as vectorized graphics ?  It should tremendously speed up the process.